# Which Tree Traversal technique should be used to evaluate (2-3) + (2*(4+3))?

Tags: stack, tree-traversal

I can use PostOrderTrversal to evaluate

(2-3) + ((4+3)*2)

to

23-43+2*+

But when I try to do the same for

(2-3)+(2*(4+3))

I get

23-243+*+

which I guess will cause issue when solving.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it won't cause any issue when solving it. Their results are exactly the same.
Why? If you draw an expression tree on both equations, you will find that nodes with + and 2 are swapped. As a result, corresponding post-order-traversal is different. It's simply that the original equations are different and make their postfix expression different.

[image]